# "Slot" depending on user id etc. sql

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I have a table like this

> id item user slot

I want the SLOT to be dependant on the user id.

If I have 4 columns

```
id: 1
user: 1
item: 1
slot: 1

id: 2
user: 1
item: 1
slot: 2

id: 3
user: 1
item: 2
slot: 3

id: 4
user: 1
item: 2
slot: 4
```

If I add a new item, it should automatically be given slot 5. But If I first, let's say, deleted (slot 2 or moved it to another slot, the new item should get slot number 2. Is this possible to with SQL?

Slot is basically the position where the "item" row is place.

An inventory would look like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18
19 20
```

Where the numbers 1-20 are the Slots. If, let's say the 4 slots above are taken by items, the next items should be assigned 5. But If I move an item (like slot 2), to like slot 20, the next item should be placed on number 2, as it not  taken now. If both 3-4 were deleted, and then an item was added, it would be placed at 3.

Comment: can you explain more the slot concept? not your example, but what it stands for and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: so you want the new entry placed into the "next smallest number available slot", correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an insert trigger to update the slot, or you could determine the first available slot yourself on insert.

As for the determening the first free slot number you can use cyclic check as others stated, or you can get a bit creative:

```
SELECT min(rnumber)
from (SELECT slot, row_number() OVER (order by slot) as rnumber from <table_name> where slot is not null) as t
where slot <> rnumber
```

This gets the smallest free slot. If all the slots are taken, then the return value is null. You have to get the next slot with max(slot)+1. 
You can use `isnull(min(rnumber), (select max(slot)+1 from <table_name>)` instead of min(rnumber) so the final query looks like this:

```
SELECT isnull(min(rnumber), (select max(slot) + 1 from <table_name>))
from (SELECT slot, row_number() OVER (order by slot) as rnumber from <table_name> where slot is not null) as t
where slot <> rnumber
```

Comment: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'

Comment: @John What db are you using? I am using MSSQL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx
If you're using MySQL you can use the COALESCE function instead of ISNULL

Answer (score 1):

> **Option  1**

You need to create a trigger on the table for insert.

Here is an example:

```
create trigger forinsertrig1 
on salesdetail 
for insert 
as 
if (select count(*) 
    from titles, inserted 
    where titles.title_id = inserted.title_id) !=
    @@rowcount 
/* Cancel the insert and print a message.*/
  begin
    rollback transaction 
    print "No, the title_id does not exist in
    titles." 
  end  
/* Otherwise, allow it. */
else
  print "Added! All title_id’s exist in titles."
```

But in the trigger you'll update the slot that doesn't have any value (the last inserted) to be the value of the first missing id.

To discover the first missing id you can do the following steps:

1. select the min(id) from the table
2. Make a cycle incrementing the id and selecting the row from the table. The first one that doesn't have a row, it's your missing slot

> **Option 2**

Another possibility, like stated by [Elzo Valugi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95353/elzo-valugi) is to use the increment logic to build a function that will return you the next available slot and make the entry directly on the insert.

Comment: you can used the increment logic to build a function that will return you the next available slot and make the entry directly